# DismissViewController passing parameter back swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I present my secondViewController from (attendanceViewController) and in dismiss completion I'm trying to pass parameters and call functions. The AttendanceViewController appears and the function is called. The problem is that all the Objects are nil when dismiss`(@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! , @IBOutlet weak var boxTypeSKU: UIView!....all)`

```
 self.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { _ i
            let attView: AttendanceViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AttendanceViewID") as! AttendanceViewController
                attView.currAttendance = self.currAttendance
                attView.searchProductWithSKU("\(sku)")

            })
```

Comment: `AttendanceViewController` may be instantiated, but all those outlets probably aren't going to be hooked up yet because of the view lifecycle process. You may need to defer calling `searchProductWithSKU` until after `-viewDidLoad` is called on `AttendanceViewController`

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using Protocols like this tutorial (http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/pass-information-back-to-the-previous-view-controller/) I think it's more elegant and efficient.

There's my updated code:

In second view Controller (BarcodeScannerViewController.swift) I do it:

```
protocol BarcodeScannerProtocol {
    func setSKUScanner(sku: String)
}


class BarcodeScannerViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
var delegate:BarcodeScannerProtocol?

func back() {
 let sku = (barcode as NSString).substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(6, 8))
 delegate?.setSKUScanner(sku)
 self.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { _ in
}

}
```

In first view controller (AttendanceViewController.swift):

```
class AttendanceViewController: UIViewController, BarcodeScannerProtocol {
   var strSKUScanner : String?

   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let skuScanned = strSKUScanner {
            searchProductWithSKU(skuScanned)
        } else {
            fetchProducts()
        }
    }

// MARK: BarcodeScannerProtocol functions
    func setSKUScanner(sku: String) {
        self.strSKUScanner = sku
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to be noticed is that a new instance of `AttendanceViewController` is being instantiated. This means that the properties are not being set on the correct object. There needs to be a reference to the view controller that presented the `secondViewController`. How that is done is up to you, but I recommend a callback containing the `currAttendance` variable. This would be a property on the presented view controller. Once the callback is called by the presented view controller, the parent `AttendanceViewController` can set its own property and dismiss the presented view controller and call the `searchProductWithSKU(_:)` method.